# Asus Laptop not posting turns off (kb backlight turns on) then turns off after a minute

Tags: boot, laptop, battery, power, post

I have an Asus FX504GE that isn't posting (screen stays black) but kb backlight turns on, then laptop turns off after a minute or so.

**Brief Background**

Bought it back in Nov/Dev 2019. It had some issues (VRAM buzzing), mousepad, etc. (post time was very fast < 5s). Asus replaced the mb, mousepad, etc and VRAM buzz was gone. I noticed posting took quite some time +30s - dismissed it as needing to do BIOS update.

**Problem (TL;DR)**

Now, it doesn't boot (i.e. it doesn't post, no Asus logo showing, only a black screen).

**Extra Details:**

The AC power adapter light turns on, the battery charging light shows orange (when charging) and white when fully charged. Thus MB is not fried.

When booting up, pressing power button (with either/or AC power & battery, same result). The keyboard backlight turns on, then it "hangs" for a while followed by it turning off after (~70s).

**Diagnosing steps:**

1. Hard reset by removing battery & AC power, hold power button for 40s (and 60s) => not working
2. Switching ram modules (I have 2 same ram modules). Switched both, only had either in and neither, same result each time => not working

My only other option is to go to Asus but if anyone has a suggestion, I would be glad to try.

Comment: You didn't mention it, but I assume you did try holding F2 while attempting to boot to enter the BIOS settings screens.

Comment: @MZB doesn't even get to the point where something is shown on screen i.e. cannot get to bios screen